# Printing out the results of my linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using asp.net core entity framework.  I am using linq to combine three tables, User, Products, and User_Had_Products.  My query seems to be working fine.  The problem I am having is printing out the results of my query.  I can print out the entire object, but cannot use dot notation to print out the individual fields.  For example the output for the object is

```
{ name = user, product = desk, quantity = 1, date = 1/13/17 3:30:32 PM }
{ name = user, product = desk, quantity = 1, date = 1/13/17 3:52:40 PM }
{ name = user, product = desk, quantity = 1, date = 1/13/17 3:52:40 PM }
{ name = user, product = desk, quantity = 1, date = 1/14/17 9:14:22 AM }
{ name = user, product = desk, quantity = 1, date = 1/14/17 9:14:27 AM }
```

What I want for output in

```
user  desk 1 1/13/17 3:30:32 PM 
user  desk 1 1/13/17 3:30:32 PM 
user  desk 1 1/13/17 3:30:32 PM 
user  desk 1 1/13/17 3:30:32 PM 
user  desk 1 1/13/17 3:30:32 PM
```

Here is my code

```
 ViewBag.User_Has_Products = from user_products in _context.Users_Has_Products
                    join user in _context.Users on user_products.users_id equals user.id 
                    join product in _context.Products on user_products.products_id equals product.id 
                    select new{name =  user.name, product = product.name, 
                    quantity = user_products.quanitity, date = user_products.created_at};

            foreach(var item in ViewBag.User_Has_Products)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
```

Comment: You have to format your output: `WriteLine($"{item.name} {tem.product} {tem.quantity} {tem.date}");`

Comment: You have to do it yourself...Either create a Custom Class instead of an anonymous type and override ToString or concatenate the strings in the WriteLine

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen, thanks.  Post your comment in answers so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to format your output:

```
WriteLine($"{item.name} {item.product} {item.quantity} {item.date}");
```